# Python: add zeroes in single digit numbers without using .zfill

Tags: micropython

Im currently using micropython and it does not have the .zfill method.
What Im trying to get is to get the YYMMDDhhmmss of the UTC.
The time that it gives me for example is

```
t = (2019, 10, 11, 3, 40, 8, 686538, None)
```

I'm able to access the ones that I need by using t[:6]. Now the problem is with the single digit numbers, the 3 and 8. I was able to get it to show 1910113408, but I need to get 19101**03**40**08** I would need to get the zeroes before those 2. I used

```
t = "".join(map(str,t))
t = t[2:]
```

So my idea was to iterate over *t* and then check if the number is less than 10. If it is. I will add zeroes in front of it, replacing the number . And this is what I came up with.

```
t = (2019, 1, 1, 2, 40, 0)
t = list(t)

for i in t:
    if t[i] < 10:
        t[i] = 0+t[i]
    t[i] = t[i] 
print(t)
```

However, this gives me **IndexError: list index out of range**
Please help, I'm pretty new to coding/python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use

```py
for i in t:
```

`i` is not index, each item.

```py
>>> for i in t:
...     print(i)
...
2019
10
11
3
40
8
686538
None
```

If you want to use index, do like following:

```py
>>> for i, v in enumerate(t):
...     print("{} is {}".format(i,v))
...
0 is 2019
1 is 10
2 is 11
3 is 3
4 is 40
5 is 8
6 is 686538
7 is None
```

another way to create '191011034008'

```py
>>> t = (2019, 10, 11, 3, 40, 8, 686538, None)
>>> "".join(map(lambda x: "%02d" % x, t[:6]))
'20191011034008'
>>> "".join(map(lambda x: "%02d" % x, t[:6]))[2:]
'191011034008'
```

note that:

1. `%02d` add leading zero when argument is lower than 10 otherwise (greater or equal 10) use itself. So year is still 4digit string.
2. This lambda does not expect that argument is None.

I tested this code at https://micropython.org/unicorn/

### edited :

str.format method version:

```py
"".join(map(lambda x: "{:02d}".format(x), t[:6]))[2:]
```

or

```py
"".join(map(lambda x: "{0:02d}".format(x), t[:6]))[2:]
```

second example's `0` is parameter index. 
You can use parameter index if you want to specify it (ex: position mismatch between format-string and params, want to write same parameter multiple times...and so on) .

```py
>>> print("arg 0: {0}, arg 2: {2}, arg 1: {1}, arg 0 again: {0}".format(1, 11, 111))
arg 0: 1, arg 2: 111, arg 1: 11, arg 0 again: 1
```

Comment: Here is document https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting . However using `string.format()` method is recommended rather than `format % value` style. You can see string.format example here https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: how would I use .format in my case? Sorry, Im a little lost.

Comment: I added to my answer and you can see more example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you to use Python's string formatting syntax.

```
>> t = (2019, 10, 11, 3, 40, 8, 686538, None)
>> r = ("%d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d" % t[:-2])[2:]
>> print(r)
191011034008
```

Let's see what's going on here:

- %d means "display a number"
- %2d means "display a number, at least 2 digits"
- %02d means "display a number, at least 2 digits, pad with zeroes"

so we're feeding all the relevant numbers, padding them as needed, and cut the "20" out of "2019".

Comment: Really simple and nice solution, Thank you! Question, what does % before the t mean? and where can I read about this string parsing with %? I have not seen anything like that from what I've read.

Comment: [This](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) is a helpful summary of the different methods for string formatting in Python, of which MicroPython implements the first two. If you want to use the `format` method, [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) is the reference description (you can probably just page down to the examples section).

Comment: Also, minor edit: *parsing* means interpreting a value from a string, e.g. from the string `20191016` get the numeric values 2019, 10 and 16. What's described in this answer is string *formatting*.